# When to use a custom view helper class in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views

I tend to do a lot with partials. They almost feel like small helper classes that take some parameters and spit out view snippets.

My question is, when is it appropriate to make a separate class for a view? Would this be appropriate for something with some additional logic like a menu system that needs to be available for testing?

I have a feeling I may be overusing partials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a helper to build a single unit of display. and you can use partial to build complex unit of display.

see [Helpers vs. Partials](http://viget.com/extend/helpers-vs-partials-a-performance-question) and [What belongs in a helper method?](http://37signals.com/svn/posts/1108-what-belongs-in-a-helper-method)